# Functional Component definition scope causing app to not work correctly, but I can't understand why

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm a React veteran but I'm fairly new to using hooks and closures in React 16 and I'm seeing something that fundamentally doesn't make sense to me. I have numerous examples in my app of the UI flickering or re-laying everything out when a state var changes, but only today when working with animations did it become apparent that it has something with the scope in which I am defining my Functional components. (The app is built on Next.js btw, in case that is relevant!)

Consider the following `ExperienceBuilder` page which allows a user to edit a document. There is a right-hand menu that can be opened and closed -- animating in and out. The state for tracking if the menu should be shown or not is managed by the parent, but the animation is handled using Tailwind CSS inside the `RightMenuContainer` Component. When I implement them in independent scopes, *everything works perfect:*

```
const RightMenuContainer = props => {
    return (
      <div className={props.isOpen ? '' :'transform translate-x-full -mr-90'}>
         {/* ...buttons and stuff... */}
      </div>
    )
}

const ExperienceBuilder = props => {
    [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)
    return (
      <>
        <RightMenuContainer isOpen={isOpen} >
        <Button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} title={isOpen ? "Show Menu" : "Hide Menu"} />
        {/* ...other stuff in the main container... */}
      </>
    )
}
```

However, once I move the `RightMenuContainer` to being defined inside of `ExperienceBuilder`, *it stops working!?!*:

```
const ExperienceBuilder = props => {
    [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)
    
    const RightMenuContainer = props => {
        return (
            <div className={props.isOpen ? '' :'transform translate-x-full -mr-90'}>
                {/* ...buttons and stuff... */}
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    return (
      <>
        <RightMenuContainer isOpen={isOpen} >
        <Button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} title={isOpen ? "Show Menu" : "Hide Menu"} />
        {/* ...other stuff in the main container... */}
      </>
    )
}
```

At this point I realize I should just implement things the first way in order to not get bugs, *but it would be really helpful to know WHY.* 99% of time the latter example works fine and bringing the child in scope is faster to code because my child component can read the parent state without needing to have the state passed in as props. My hope is if I can understand what is going on under the hood, I can make better design decisions about when it is worth while to cut the corner and bring the component in scope, and when it is not.

Things I tried that did not help:

- Memoizing the functional component with `React.memo`
- Changing the props variable names to avoid potential collision with the state variable name

Comment: you mean the animation stops to work or something else in the component?

Comment: The animation does not work. The Component just renders itself off screen instantly.

I see similar issue with Images that are defined inside `ExperienceBuilder`, where they flicker and reload their contents from URL whenever the state of `ExperienceBuilder` changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your component is being mounted and unmounted all over, if you add `useEffect` you will see that:

```
const RightMenuContainer = props => {
    useEffect(() => console.log('mount'),[]) // empty array only executes on mount

    return (
        <div className={props.isOpen ? '' :'transform translate-x-full -mr-90'}>
            {/* ...buttons and stuff... */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

On every `ExperienceBuilder` rerender a new `RightMenuContainer` function is created. Since the animation only takes places if the component is already mounted then the animation doesn't work.

To solve this, in your case wrap your function with [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), with a second empty array `[]` as argument to memoize your function:

```
const RightMenuContainer = React.useCallback(props => {
    useEffect(()=>{console.log('mount')}, [])

    return (
        <div className={props.isOpen ? '' :'transform translate-x-full -mr-90'}>
          {/* ...buttons and stuff... */}
        </div>
    )
},[])
```

that way it will memoize your function component and you can check that `console.log('mount')` will display only once

Comment: This the the correct answer as to *why*, but creating the component with `useCallback` seems silly to me.  Just define it outside the parent!  I'm of the opinion that all components should exist at the top level.